# Why is this crystal so tall?

Tags: crystal, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the frequency of a crystal influence its height?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/does-the-frequency-of-a-crystal-influence-its-height)

I am looking at s and saw that there are some odd shaped packages.  Is there a  case where such a [tall](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FOXLF250F-20/631-1092-ND/1024684)  (13.46mm) would be ?

[image]

For comparison a ["regular"](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/9B-25.000MAAE-B/887-1499-ND/2690352)  (3.68mm)

[image]

The specs and price between these two seem very similar.  I was just curious to know if there is a reason for such a package?

Comment: Top one is a bit older model, bottom one younger. Better manufacturing methods, smaller size.